# Common Triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let's say I have 40 triangles, all different in terms of size and type. How can I find a common triangle that can be merged to rebuild the original triangles? Basically, how do I find a common triangle shared in all other triangles?

Comment: $40$ different triangles will almost certainly require a minimum of $42$ data points to differentiate between them.  However, it is possible to encode certain classes of triangles as ellipses, then you may be able to get away with specifying one triangle and a set of angular offsets within the encoded ellipse.  How would you "merge" a "common triangle" to retrieve the individual ones?

Comment: The question is unclear. What does it mean to "merge" a triangle to "rebuild" some other triangle?

Comment: Show us what a common triangle of, say, two or three triangles is.

Comment: I basically need to split multiple triangles into equal triangles.

Comment: If you have a triangle of area 1, and a triangle of area $\sqrt2$, there is no way to split those two triangles into equal triangles.

Comment: There must be a triangle size that you could split the two triangles into to get the same size triangles all around?

Comment: If you could do that, then 1 and $\sqrt2$ would both be integer multiples of that triangle size, which would make $\sqrt2$ rational --- which it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from the discussion in the comments that what OP wants to do is to find a triangle $T$ such that each of the 40 given triangles can be dissected into copies of $T$. However, this may be impossible, even for 2 given triangles:

Suppose given a triangle $A$ of area 1 and a triangle $B$ of area $\sqrt2$, and it be desired to find a triangle $T$ such that $A$ and $B$ can each be cut up into copies of $T$. Let the area of $T$ be $c$, and let $A$ be cut up into $m$ copies of $T$, and $B$ into $n$ copies of $T$. Then $$mc=1;\qquad nc=\sqrt2$$ Dividing the second equation by the first, we get $${n\over m}=\sqrt2$$ But it is well-known that $\sqrt2$ is irrational, so this equation is impossible, so no such triangle $T$ exists.